# CLR C++ syntax question about GetElementsByTagName

Tags: .net, xml, c++-cli, getelementsbytagname

I'm newbie in c++. I have xml file and this code:

```
XmlDocument^ xml = gcnew XmlDocument();
xml -> Load( "url.xml" );

box -> Text = xml -> DocumentElement -> GetElementsByTagName("item") -> Item(0) -> GetElementsByTagName("title") -> Item(0) -> InnerXml; // This code doesnt work.
```

and xml file:

```
 <item>
      <pubDate>date</pubDate>
      <title>title</title>
      <author>author</author>
      <description>description</description
 </item>
 <item>
 ...
```

I want get title tag from first Item. And I dont know how. Help please.

**upd.**
I tried this code, but it not work :(

```
xml -> DocumentElement -> GetElementsByTagName("item") -> Item(0) -> ChildNodes  -> GetElementsByTagName("title") -> Item(0) -> InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I call `xml.LoadXml()` using a string that copies what you have for your file, I get an error that `</description` doesn't have an end `>`. If I fix that, I get an `XmlException` because you have multiple root elements. If I remove the second `<item>`, then I can get this to give me the title (converted on the fly from my C# code):

```
XmlElement^ item = (XmlElement)(xml->GetElementsByTagName("item")->Item(0));
string^ title = item->GetElementsByTagName("title")->Item(0)->InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine.

```
System::String ^ item =  xml -> DocumentElement -> GetElementsByTagName("item")->Item(0) -> OuterXml;

XmlDocument^ xmlt = gcnew XmlDocument();
xmlt -> LoadXml( item );

System::String^ title = xmlt -> DocumentElement -> GetElementsByTagName("title")->Item(0)-> OuterXml;

box -> Text = title;
```